# Most dense subset of numbers that avoids arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, additive-combinatorics, arithmetic-progression

The famous Green-Tao theorem says that there exist arbitrarily long sequences of primes in arithmetic progression.
I am wondering: How dense can a subset $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ be and still avoid
arbitrarily long sequences of elements of $S$ in arithmetic progression?
To make this more precise (following a comment by Robert Israel),

> ***Q***. What is the cardinality of the largest subset $S_n$ of $[1,n]=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$
>   that avoids $k$-term arithmetic progressions of elements in $S_n$,
>   as a function of $n$ and $k$?

As $n \to \infty$, can the density be significantly more dense than the primes density, $n / \log_e n$?

I suspect this is a well-studied question, in which case quotes and/or pointers would suffice. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming the Erdős conjecture (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions), it can't be significantly more dense than the primes.

Comment: Do you mean "... that avoids arithmetic progressions of length $k$, as a function of $n$ and $k$"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Good point! Even $k=3$ seems nontrivial... I was primarily interested in the density as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: There is some discussion in E10 of Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory, although what's there may well be out of date by now.

Comment: If you're interested in lower bounds for the largest set without a $k$-AP, then Behrend's construction is still essentially the best known, and it gives a set of size $n\exp(-c\sqrt{\log n})$ for some constant $c>0$.  See this recent paper of Green and Wolf: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.0732v1.pdf

Comment: Thought it would be worth linking to Section 2 of this survey of Gowers on this question as well (since it discusses this problem in detail): https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.03421

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are essentially asking for quantitative estimates on Szemerédi's theorem, which states that the largest subset of $[1,n]$ without a k-term arithmetic progression has size $o(n)$. To be precise, let us define $r_k(n)$ to be the largest subset of [1,n] with no k-term arithmetic progression. Then a construction due to Behrend (essentially projecting a high-dimensional sphere onto the integers) shows that 
$$
r_3(n) = \Omega\left(n e^{-c \sqrt{\log n}}\right),
$$
while a result of Bloom (moderately improving on a result of Sanders), shows that
$$
r_3(n) = O\left(n \frac{(\log \log n)^4}{\log n}\right). 
$$
For general $k$, the best known upper bound is due to Gowers and says that
$$
r_k(n) = O\left(\frac{n}{(\log \log n)^{c_k}}\right)
$$
for an appropriate $c_k$. Behrend's construction clearly provides a lower bound in this case as well, but may be improved a little by projecting a collection of concentric spheres. There is some evidence (see, for example, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.2568.pdf) to believe that the lower bound is closer to the truth.

Comment: Thanks especially for the thumbnail of the construction ("projecting a high-dimensional sphere onto the integers").

Comment: I worked out the lower bound in detail (you can do slightly better than concentric spheres by using concentric spherical annuli and then throwing out a few terms): http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v18i1p59

Answer (score 8):

If a sequence avoids three term arithmetic progressions it is less than ((log log N)^4)N/log N according to "A Quantitative improvement for Roths’s Theorem
On Arithmetic Progressions" which is available [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.5800v2.pdf)

The above preprint also claims that the result of "On Roth’s Theorem On Progressions" availabe on arxiv [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.0104)
is in error in claiming O(((log log N)^5 N/log N) and that it should be
O(((log log N)^6 N/log N).

So the upper bound even for three term arithmetic progressions is at most a factor of log log N to the fourth power better than N/log N if the preprint in the first paragraph is correct.