# References on Erdos conjecture on arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, l-functions

Erdos conjectured that any set  $ A $ of positive integers such that  $ \sum_{n\in A}\dfrac{1}{n} $ diverges contains arbitrary long arithmetic progressions. The celebrated Green-Tao theorem is a special case of this conjecture, where  $ A $ is the set of primes.

I would like to have references on this conjecture, and also to know if considering a set  $ S $ of L-functions whose elements  $ F : s\mapsto\sum_{n>0}\dfrac{a_{n}}{n^{s}} $ can help shed a light on it through 'twisting'  $ F $  by the function  $ 1_{A} : n\mapsto 1 $ iff  $ n\in A $ and  $ 1_{A}(n)=0 $ otherwise.

Comment: Related (to some extent): [The Erdős-Turán conjecture or the Erdős' conjecture?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/132648) This was linked in the Wikipedia article [Erdős conjecture on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MR3203599 Gowers, W. Timothy, Erdős and arithmetic progressions. Erdős Centennial, 265–287, Bolyai Soc. Math. Stud., 25, János Bolyai Math. Soc., Budapest, 2013. The review says the author gives a survey of progress on the conjecture (and on another conjecture of Erdős).

Comment: The arxiv version is at https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.03421. A related question is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198387/most-dense-subset-of-numbers-that-avoids-arbitrarily-long-arithmetic-progression, also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232023/has-erdős-conjecture-on-arithmetic-progressions-been-proved